# How to enter multiple colors for Google Schema Product?

Tags: html, schema, metadata, meta, schema.org

Some of the products in my shop have multiple colors associated with them. Does Google consider multiple colors in the schema and is this the valid way to do it?

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
Other items....
    <span itemprop="color"> Color 1 </span>
    <span itemprop="color"> Color 2 </span>
    <span itemprop="color"> Color 3 </span>
</div>
```

Below is the screenshot from Google Structured Data Testing Tool
[image]

Comment: color `Expected Type` is text - so yes (Write "red, blue, green"). More semantic to write a list of colors as `ul` or `ol` list if you using `microdata`.

Comment: @EzraSiton Should I type in as separate child elements to them itemscope or enter all values in 1 child element sepearated by comma?

Comment: No difference. Use `red | blue` -- `red / blue` or `red, blue`. The semantic meaning is the same. Keep in mind there is not a lot of official docs related to this issue (Google not yet support color for rich-results and/or color variants) https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/product#product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the following Google recommendation from their guide **[Follow the structured data guidelines](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/sd-policies#completeness)**:

> Completeness
>
> The more recommended properties that you provide, the
>   higher quality the result is to user.

Therefore, using multi colors to present your products can be a good solution.

The example of marking up microdata presented by you, at first sight, is technically correct. However, one must take into account the fact that according to the same guide:

> Relevance
>
> Your structured data should be a true representation of the
>   page content.

therefore, accurately determining the correctness of your microdata is probably not possible with the information provided.

Due to the fact that users may not know the meaning for the color such as Pantone 5773, it may be useful to set a color name that is understandable to all users, which you can get from the **[W3 color table](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_colornames.asp)**. For machines, you can set identification for each of your colors. In this case, it is worth considering the fact that you represent the color in the HTML document, so it may be useful to use the identifier used in **[Web-color](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors)**, for example, the color HEX or RGB. To convert Pantone to HEX or RGB, you can use the free online tool **[Pantone to HEX](https://codebeautify.org/pantone-to-hex-converter)**. Thus, your microdata identifier for Pantone 7413C may be as follows:

```
<meta property=color content=#DC8633>
```